# Sampling pairs of nodes with given distance between them

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, random

*For the purposes of this question we assume undirected and connected graphs.*

I am trying to learn how to efficiently find pairs of nodes in a graph that are separated by prescribed distance $d.$ One direct approach would be:

- `GraphDistance` can be used to find the distance between 2 given nodes.
- `GraphDistanceMatrix` on the other hand, computes the distance between all pairs of nodes. For example its element `[[i,j]]` is the shortest path distance between nodes `i` and `j.`
- `Position` can then be used to find all occurrences for a given distance value in the distance matrix.

---

Below is an example:

```
SeedRandom[123];
n = 15;
m = 20;
gr = RandomGraph[{n, m}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
distmat = GraphDistanceMatrix[gr];
(*finding all pairs at distance 2*)
pos2 = Position[UpperTriangularize@distmat, 2]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 6}, {1, 13}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 
>   12}, {3, 14}, {4, 7}, {4, 10}, {4, 14}, {5, 6}, {5, 8}, {5, 12}, {6,
>   13}, {6, 14}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {7, 10}, {7, 11}, {7, 15}, {8,    10},
>   {9, 15}, {10, 11}, {10, 14}, {14, 15}}

```
(*Sanity check:*)
GraphDistance[gr, #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ pos2
```

> {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
>   \ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}

---

**Questions:**

- For larger graphs ($n\approx 5000$ and $m\approx 10000$), my approach seems to scale poorly. My own understanding of the slowness is that, I am: computing all distances using `GraphDistanceMatrix`, instead of skipping all those that are $>d$ anyhow, and I am finding all occurrences of $d$ with `Position` instead of a smaller select of them. Knowing I am interested only in pairs with distance $d$, could one optimize the calculation of `GraphDistanceMatrix`?
- Would it be altogether faster, if instead of trying to find all instances, one sampled for a smaller select $n$ of pairs with distance $d$? Or possibly, approximating the problem by finding pairs that are at most $d$ apart.

Any hints and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can map `AdjacencyList[]` all over your graph's vertices, and then delete dupes.

Comment: GraphDistanceMatrix[g, d] will give you the distance only up to a maximal distance d (equivalent to skipping all those that are > d as you ask in your first question)

It appears that Mathematica uses Dijkstra's algorithm for this (as a possible choice); there are variants for bounded arc weights (which is your problem), where the computational complexity is linearly proportional to the edge weight.  (although I'm not sure if Mathematica implements these special cases) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Specialized_variants

Comment: How large a `d` are you interested in?

Comment: @CarlWoll For example in what I am calculating now, about half the diameter, which  would be $d\approx 30.$

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier Unfortunately, `GraphDistanceMatrix[g,d]` even with `d=2,` is slower than computing the whole matrix `GraphDistanceMatrix[g].`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`VertexComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexComponent.html) to find all vertices precisely at a certain distance from a given vertex.

For example, in your graph, these are the vertices at distance 4 from vertex 12:

```
VertexComponent[gr, 12, {4}]
(* {8, 2, 6} *)
```

I recommend using Mathematica 12.1 for this. `VertexComponent` is known to sometimes return incorrect result in M12.0 and earlier.